# Is Ubuntu 10.04 suitable for working on for web development

Tags: linux, ubuntu, web-development

Im just wondering what everyone's experiences are with the latest Ubuntu 10.04 version? Is it stable enough for a working environment?

I require it for web development, so using VMs, IDEs, connecting to VPNs, SSH to servers, etc. 
Im currently using 9.04 and found 9.10 unstable and problematic at times (such as problems connecting to VPN)

Any input would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes we are using it right now on many machines, since it has the "LTS" designation it is slated for more attention than other releases as they'll maintain "Long Term Support" for it.

Go for it!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is very stable seeing as how it is now out of beta.  I use it quite a bit and it suits my needs very well without being at all crashy or buggy.